# How to dereference a pointer to a structure pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

I have been working around with the bsd-list. And I wrote a very simple program to insert simple integer elements by creating the list. The code is as follows.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"bsd-list.h"

using namespace std;

struct foo {
    int a;
    LIST_ENTRY(foo) pointers; // pointers is the object of the structure generated by List Entry
} *temp, *var, *ptr;

LIST_HEAD(foo_list, foo);

int main(void)
{
    LIST_HEAD(foo_list, foo) head;
    LIST_INIT(&head);

    struct foo *item1 = new foo;
    struct foo *item2 = new foo;
    struct foo *item3 = new foo;
    item1->a = 60;
    item2->a = 120;
    item3->a = 240;
    LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&head, item1, pointers);
    LIST_INSERT_AFTER(item1, item2, pointers);
    LIST_INSERT_BEFORE(item2, item3, pointers);

    //Displaying inner details of list
    {
        cout<<"HEAD's Address : "<<head.lh_first<<endl;
        cout<<"Item 1 next value : "<<(item1)->pointers.le_next<<endl;
        cout<<"Item 1 prev value : "<<*(item1)->pointers.le_prev<<endl;
        cout<<"HEAD's Address : "<<head.lh_first<<endl;
        cout<<"Item 2 next value : "<<item2->pointers.le_next<<endl;
        cout<<"Item 2 prev value : "<<*(item1)->pointers.le_prev<<endl;
        cout<<"HEAD's Address : "<<head.lh_first<<endl;
        cout<<"Item 3 next value : "<<item3->pointers.le_next<<endl;
        cout<<"Item 3 prev value : "<<*(item3)->pointers.le_prev<<endl;
    }

    ptr = head.lh_first;
    for(;;ptr = ptr->pointers.le_next)
    {
        cout<<ptr->a<<endl;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

using the statement `*(item1)->pointers.le_prev` I am getting the value at the address contained in `le_prev`.

However I want to do something like `**(item1)->pointers.le_prev` so that I get the value 60. But I am getting errors.  What is the proper syntax to correctly use dereferencing?

Comment: C or C++, which is it? **Do not use this code in C++**, it’s bad. C++ has vastly superior tools for this. (Oh, and it’s invalid C code, so it’s really the worst of both worlds.)

Comment: Try adding `()` where they make sense, they really brighten up the code. Also, what are the "errors"

Comment: Sir, this is C but there is a network simulator known as ns2 (u probably must be knowing about that). So for maintaining a routing table a protocol uses the bsd-list. In order to understand its functionality i was working around with this. And sir can u specify superior methods for this

Comment: The errors i get is :no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"Item 1 prev 
 value : ")) << * * item1->foo::pointers.foo::<anonymous struct>::le_prev’

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for NULL :

```
for(;;ptr = ptr->pointers.le_next)
{
    if(ptr==NULL) break;
    cout<<ptr->a<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The program i have given above works completely fine. Its just i want to use ** instead of single * to display value of item1->info.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the stream output operator, `<<`, for your struct.

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const foo& data)
{
    return stream << data.a;
}
```